# Cant create Cassandra Pojo Sink

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-flink, cassandra-3.0

I'm working with Flink 1.1.3, Cassandra 3.8, and I want to create a CassandraSink for a streamining job, so I have to use POJO, here is what I got:

```
public class StreamingJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set up the streaming execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();


    Properties properties = new Properties();
    //properties to connect with kafka

    DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(/*kafka connection*/);

    CassandraSink.addSink(stream)
            .setClusterBuilder(new ClusterBuilder() {
                @Override
                public Cluster buildCluster(Cluster.Builder builder) {
                    return builder.addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
                }
            })
            .build();
    //print messages
    stream.rebalance()
            .flatMap(new DeserializeJson())
            .filter(new EventFilter())
            .<Tuple2<String, String>>project(2, 5)
            .keyBy(0)
            .print();
    // execute program


    env.execute("Streaming Job");
}
```

And the table

```
@Table(keyspace = "flinktest", name = "eventos")
public class Eventos implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "ad_id")
    private byte[] adId;
    @Column(name = "event_time")
    private String eventTime;

    public Eventos(byte[] adId, String eventTime){
        this.adId = adId;
        this.eventTime = eventTime;
    }

    public byte[] getAdId() {
        return adId;
    }

    public void setId(byte[] adId) {
        this.adId = adId;
    }

    public String getEventTime() {
        return eventTime;
    }

    public void setEventTime(String eventTime) {
        this.eventTime = eventTime;
    }
}
```

When I run it without the CassandraSink I've got no problem and the job cosume from kafka normally. When I add the sink, I get this errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create CassandraPojoSink with input: String
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.cassandra.CassandraPojoSink.open(CassandraPojoSink.java:53)
at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:38)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:91)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:376)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:256)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:585)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Table annotation was not found on type java.lang.String
at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AnnotationChecks.getTypeAnnotation(AnnotationChecks.java:39)
at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AnnotationParser.parseEntity(AnnotationParser.java:50)
at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.getMapper(MappingManager.java:154)
at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.mapper(MappingManager.java:110)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.cassandra.CassandraPojoSink.open(CassandraPojoSink.java:51)
```

I don't know why "@Table" is causing the problem since it is imported from another library (datastax). Any clue on how to solve this? It is getting annoying since I can't get it to work with the cassandra Sink and the [examples](https://www.codatlas.com/github.com/apache/flink/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-cassandra/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/cassandra/example/CassandraPojoSinkExample.java) that i've found doesn't help to much.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/85a19bd4b148ea6165410218f7a627455b404e9c/flink-connectors/flink-connector-cassandra/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/cassandra/CassandraPojoSink.java#L59 Try Defining a CassandraPojoSink and not just regular CassandraSink and see what happens.

Comment: Actually found the error. The ```DataStream<String> stream``` is the problem, since it is a String type, it must be ```Eventos``` to work with the CassandraSink. But this generates other problems.

Comment: did your program worked when you added Eventos instead of String because I am stuck with the same issue.I am able to write to Cassandra when I use DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>>  but get error when using a custom type

Comment: @AmarjitSingh I had the same problem. Only worked with string, couldn't use any other type.

Comment: CassandraDataSink with a Pojo is working fine for me. If you have explicit  cassandra driver dependency try commenting it out as flink cassandra connector has the driver and I was getting conflicts. BTW, my flink version is 1.3.2 and cassandra connector _2.11.