# Saving POJO to Cassandra using Flink

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Flink, and I wanted to store Kafka streaming data into Cassandra. I've converted String into POJO. My POJO as below,

```
@Table(keyspace = "sample", name = "contact")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "timeStamp")
    private LocalDateTime timeStamp;
```

and My conversion takes places as below,

```
 stream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Person>() {
            public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Person> out) {
                try {
                    out.collect(objectMapper.readValue(value, Person.class));
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).print(); // I need to use proper method to convert to Datastream.
        env.execute();
```

I read document on the below link for reference,

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/cassandra.html

The Cassandra Sink accepts DataStream instance. I need to convert my conversion and store them into Kafka.

[Cant create Cassandra Pojo Sink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989340/cant-create-cassandra-pojo-sink) gives me also some idea.

There is method `.forward()` which returns  `DataStream<Reading> forward`, and when pass  the instance to,

```
 CassandraSink.addSink(forward)
                .setHost("localhost")
                .build();
```

```
cannot access org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream
```

How can i convert my POJO to store in Cassandra?

Comment: Hi ! Could you please provide the source code of your solution ? From what I can see above, `env.execute();` should be executed after the `CassandraSink.addSink(forward)`, but this is just a guess. The full pipeline code will help to understand your issue. Thank you.

Comment: Sure i will send you the source code details.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/thangavel-projects/615f28a084b224cdf17b0313aa2ef924
https://gist.github.com/thangavel-projects/b3cc438a3f2e18f3542a3f4987868f13
https://gist.github.com/thangavel-projects/ab606a25760e344e54a6535e08cff632

Comment: Does this thread resolves the original question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388198/flink-not-emitting-value-to-store-in-cassandra

Comment: Unfortunately nope, i face some memory leak exception though i followed rules for POJO.

Comment: Is the question still relevant ?