# Flink Not Emitting Value to Store in Cassandra

Tags: apache-flink

I have following POJO class,

```
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Column;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Table;

@Table(keyspace = "testKey", name = "contact")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "timeStamp")
    private LocalDateTime timeStamp;
}
```

and Mapper code is,

```
DataStream<Reading> sideOutput = stream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Person>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Person> out) throws Exception {
                try {
                    out.collect(objectMapper.readValue(value, Person.class));
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).getSideOutput(new OutputTag<>("contact", TypeInformation.of(Person.class)));

 env.execute();
 
 CassandraSink.addSink(sideOutput)
                .setHost("localhost")
                .setMapperOptions(() -> new Mapper.Option[]{Mapper.Option.saveNullFields(true)})
                .build();
```

It's not working without `.getSideOutput(new OutputTag<>("contact", TypeInformation.of(Person.class)));` also.

The `sideOutput` is not emitting value to store in Cassandra. any idea where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, `env.execute();` should be called after the pipeline is build, i.e. after the `CassandraSink` and would get rid of side output. Somethink like this should work:

```java
DataStream<Reading> ds = stream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Person>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Person> out) throws Exception {
                try {
                    out.collect(objectMapper.readValue(value, Person.class));
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
 
 CassandraSink.addSink(ds)
                .setHost("localhost")
                .setMapperOptions(() -> new Mapper.Option[]{Mapper.Option.saveNullFields(true)})
                .build();


 env.execute();
```

Comment: I tried with executing ```env.execute();```. after pipeline is build, then the error is ```No support for the type of the given DataStream: GenericType<com.streaming.model.Person>
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.cassandra.CassandraSink.addSink(CassandraSink.java:228)```

Comment: This is the lack of `TypeInformation` issue for `Person` class. This specifies a number of rules for POJO: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/types_serialization.html#rules-for-pojo-types. Could you please ensure all rules are satisfied ?

Comment: Fist, I would add a public no-args constructor to `Person` and would define public getter- and a setter- methods that follows the Java beans naming conventions for getters and setters for fields `name` and `timeStamp`.

Comment: I've followed the rules of ```TypeInformation```, the ```Person``` class contains getters, setters. I face some strange memory leak exception,
https://gist.github.com/thangavel-projects/2e382ffe6eab3037649f341f88c25032

Comment: So, right now the job starts, but the memory leak exception is reported ? Is the job running or not ?

Comment: the memory leak exception is solved, and during execution of the job ```com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [varchar <-> int]``` pop up. I'm looking into that.